# How do I add content to views slideshow after setting up?

Tags: views, javascript

I set up a slideshow according to instructions and it functions beautifully, but when I add more content the slideshow block does not seem to be pulling it.  Is there another way to add additional images to the slideshow?  I have the block/view set to all items, rather than a set number.

Comment: No way to answer this question without seeing your exact Views configuration. Most likely there is some filter or other setting requirement in your View that your new nodes aren't meeting - such as being published or marked as "promoted to front page".

Comment: Hi @vlsb. It will help if you can give any reference of _"I set up a slideshow according to instructions"_ Thanks.